# Webrick does not start when starting a Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Any idea why Webrick refuses to start?

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'slim'

class Blog < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    slim :home
  end
end
```

Running `ruby blog.rb` does nothing. No error is raised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in web server isn’t started when using the modular style of Sinatra apps. See [the docs for the differences between modular and classic styles](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Modular%20vs.%20Classic%20Style).

To get it to run like a classic style app, add this line to the bottom of your `Blog` class:

```
run! if app_file == $0
```

Comment: Thanks. The serve now starts, which was my question. But for some reason I get a `404` even though I have a root path defined. Any idea why?

Comment: OK. I think that line has to be at the bottom of the class, below everything else.

Comment: I found another issue... If I want to use shotgun for automatic reloads, I get the 404 again...